# An infinite packing in the plane with density $0$

Tags: packing-problem

> Let $P$ be a packing in $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of infinitely many unit disks. Is it possible for $P$ to have density $0$?

For clarification:

> A packing $P$ of $D \subset$ $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a set of unit disks with pairwise disjoint interior. Density is defined as
>
> $$\rho(P, D) = \frac{\text{Area covered by the disks of P}}{\text{Area of }D}$$
>
> In case of infinite packings we have to be a bit more careful: Let $P_D \subset P$ such that each disk in $P_D$ is completely contained in $D$. We further define $Box(n) = [-n,n] \times [-n,n]$. The density of $P$ is then given by
>
> $$\rho(P) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} sup \ \rho(P_{Box(n)},Box(n))$$

I suppose that the claim is true, but I can not find an example. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: What is the definition of "packing"?  (And of "density"?)

Comment: @GEdgar: I made an edit.

Comment: Let the $n$th unit disk be at distance $n!$ from the origin.